# Set Expiry Date with CSV containing DD-MMM-YYYY format

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Our HR Department's Termination system sends us a report at intermittent intervals of people who are leaving/people who have left.

```
    Import-Csv -Path \C\Users\Leaver.csv | ForEach-Object {
        $EmployeeNumber = $_.EmployeeNumber
        $TerminationDate = $_.TerminationDate
        $objADUser = (Get-ADUser -Filter {employeeid -eq $EmployeeNumber}).samAccountName
}
```

The report that HR give us doesn't have their sAMAccountName or even their email. Fortunately, it does have their Employee ID. I'm using this in the script to get their SAM name since I figure that's easier to work with.

Problem is, the termination date they give is actually the last day they work, not the first day of non-work.

Normally I'd have

```
Set-ADAccountExpiration -Identity $objADUser -DateTime "$TerminationDate"
```

But that means they can't work on their last day. I also can't add a time like "23:59:59" as Powershell doesn't seem to like that with a variable.

There's also the fact that the date format is in DD-MMM-YYYY (EG 01-Jan-2000) which does make it difficult to work with.

Anyone know what the best syntax to use here is?

Comment: If the users are on different TimeZones this will become an issue very quickly. You could add 1 day to the date given by HR. i.e.: `$TerminationDate = (Get-Date '01-Jan-2000').AddDays(1)` but that also might be an issue. HR should give you the exact Date Time when user's should be disabled (including the TimeZone).

Comment: also `-DateTime` takes a `DateTime` instance, you don't need to use quotes there (`"$TerminationDate"` will stringify the instance - don't use quotes)

Comment: Users will always be in the same timezone for what that's worth. But I don't quite get where you do: $TerminationDate = (Get-Date '01-Jan-2000').AddDays(1) Can I do the Get-Date from the CSV?

Comment: For sure, try with `(Get-Date $_.TerminationDate).AddDays(1)`